# Angular - multiple optional route parameters

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I can't believe I can't find this situation already covered here in SO:
(I found examples with additional parameter with and without for each single route, but it's unacceptable)

So I have

```
RouterModule.forRoot([      
  {
      path: 'home',
      component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
      path: 'news',
      component: NewsComponent
  },     
  {
      path: 'newsDetail/:id',
      component: NewsDetailComponent
  },  
...
})
```

So the example URLs would be

```
http://somewhere.com/home 
http://somewhere.com/news
http://somewhere.com/newsDetail/10
```

What if I want to add optional parameter to each of those URLs, so I can explicitly call another localization directly in URL (for permalinks):

```
http://somewhere.com/home/en 
http://somewhere.com/news/en
http://somewhere.com/newsDetail/10/en
```

So it should work with and without "/en" at the end - and of course adding to each and every route (same route with optional /:language) is not the answer (imagine dozens of pages involved, many of them already with their own parameters)

Comment: It's more common to use `http://somewhere.com/en/newsDetail`, which you can regulate with `baseHref` or with a simple router configuration

Comment: OK, I don0t care about the nomenclature of parameters, which is first, which second; but I can't use baseHref, it would mean refresh of the page, wouldn't it? I want user to click "EN" button and be routed from http://somewhere.com/home to http://somewhere.com/en/home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the language parameter to be the first, you can do the following. You will first have to declare an empty app or whatever root component and use this in the bootstrap instead of the `AppComponent`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class RootComponent {}
```

Then create a module from your current routes, if you do not have that already. Call it `AppRoutingModule`.

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [      
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'news', component: NewsComponent },     
  { path: 'newsDetail/:id', component: NewsDetailComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forFeature(AppRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Then create a `RootRoutingModule`, which will do the magic:

```
export const RootRoutes: Routes = [      
  { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./app.module').then((m) => m.AppModule) },
  { path: 'en', loadChildren: () => import('./app.module').then((m) => m.AppModule) }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class RootRoutingModule {}
```

The issue with this, is that you'll have to hardcode all the languages you might support, as I don't think a `:language` parameter will work

So basically, create a root module which will do the language routing and the bootstrapping

Comment: Thank you! I actually solved it in the meantime with the querystring, but this looks like more Angular way.